# How to interrupt sleep when the app shuts down

Tags: go

I have a simple golang application that, under a certain condition, does some work. If the condition is not met, then the application goes to sleep.

```
func main() {

    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    defer cancel()
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case <-ctx.Done():
                break
            default:
                if condition {
                    //do something
                } else {
                    time.Sleep(1 * time.Minute)
                }
            }

        }
    }()
    signChan := make(chan os.Signal, 5)
    signal.Notify(signChan, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)
    <-signChan
    cancel() 
    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("Shutdown")
}
```

How can I interrupt sleep when the app is turned off?

Answer (score 0):

```
for {
            select {
            case <-ctx.Done():
                break
            default:
                if condition {
                    //do something
                } else {
                    time.Sleep(1 * time.Minute)
                }
            }
        }
```

Since you're calling `time.Sleep` in the `default` case, the `ctx.Done()` can't cancel it.

Instead, use (`time.After`)[https://pkg.go.dev/time#After], which returns a channel to which you'll receive a `time.Time` when the timer expires.  This way, instead of having a default case, you have 2 channels and can `select` from whichever comes first.

[Here is a working example](https://go.dev/play/p/EKJasVwCXJN)

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    defer cancel()
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        defer fmt.Println("Worker shutdown")
        for {
            select {
            case <-ctx.Done():
                return
            case <-time.After(1 * time.Second):
                fmt.Println("check for work")
            }
        }
    }()
    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
    cancel()
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Shutdown")
}
```

I've also taken a few liberties with this example to make it more ergonomic:

- so that it can work on playground, took out interrupt and replaced with a sleep.  In real life, the interrupt could call `cancel()`
- So that we can be sure on shutdown that the worker goroutine is done, added a `sync.WaitGroup` so the main thread can wait for it.

Comment: In the description of timer.After there is a remark: `The underlying Timer is not recovered by the garbage collector until the timer fires`. But I'm not sure I understand correctly what problems this can lead to in this code.  I tried to use NewTimer, but it turns out that it needs to be recreated every time? https://go.dev/play/p/yaQ4MeFp2gi

Comment: Just now I noticed that in your example there will always be a one-second wait between iterations, while in my example there will be a wait only if the condition is not met

Comment: `if condition` is not reproducible code.  But if figure out how you can fit that condition into a channel and add it to the `select`